# How to get app control extra data from app control which made by web application in native?

Tags: web, tizen

I want to launch native application with data by app_control in web application.
I can't find get app control extra data in my native application.
I already tried to use 'app_control_get_extra_data', 'app_control_foreach_extra_data'.

Let me know how to get extra data from web application's app control.

In my web application,

```
    // Define the data structure describing application control details
    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                   "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   [new tizen.ApplicationControlData("key",
                                                     ["data1", "data2"])] );

    // Launch an application with the specified application control
    tizen.application.launchAppControl(
            appControl,
            "net.msalt.myApplicationAppID",
            successCallback,
            errorCallback,
            appControlReplyCallback
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! :)

If 'data' length == 1, USE ***'app_control_get_extra_data()'***

```
    // In Web Application
    // Define the data structure describing application control details
    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                   "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   [new tizen.ApplicationControlData("key",
                                                     ["data1"])] );

    //In Native Application
    char *value = NULL;
    ret = app_control_get_extra_data(app_control, "key", &value);
    if (ret != APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Failed to app_control_get_extra_data(). Can't get extra data.");
    } else {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "data [%s]", value);
    }
```

If 'data' length > 1, USE ***'app_control_get_extra_data_array()'***

```
    // In Web Application
    // Define the data structure describing application control details
    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
                   "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   [new tizen.ApplicationControlData("key",
                                                     ["data1", "data2"])] );

    //In Native Application
    char **array = NULL;
    ret = app_control_get_extra_data_array(app_control, "key", &array, &length);
    if (ret != APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "Failed to app_control_get_extra_data_array(). Can't get extra data.");
    } else {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "data [%s], [%s]", array[0], array[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Message Port. Tizen provides Message Port for data communication between apps. Please check the..

[Message Port Web Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/message-port)

[Message Port Web API Ref](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/messageport.html)

[Message Port Native Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-data-exchange/message-port)

[Message Port Native API Ref](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MESSAGE__PORT__MODULE.html)

Check the Message port data Sending code from web app, and Message port data Receiving code from native app. They can communicate if you give the port a common name suppose "SAMPLE_PORT".

Note that both apps should be signed with same author certificate.

Comment: Thank you. But I am finding solution not work-around. I know Message Port well. But I think app control is best way and app control should work well in this case.